# Captive Runtime Bundle with AIR native extension

Tags: air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'm trying to export a release build of my app which makes use of AIR native extensions. Due to certain requirements, the app needs to be exported as a captive runtime bundle package.

Flash Builder 4.6 refuses to do such an export and displays this message"Native extensions are being used in the project but are not supported by the CAPTIVE_RUNTIME_BUNDLE package type. Runtime issues can occur."

Does anyone know exactly what these runtime issues are?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue in a project I'm involved in. Flash Builder 4.6 doesn't support an export as a captive runtime bundle when the project includes AIR native extensions. But I managed this in Flash Builder 4.7 without any problems (Also see http://forums.adobe.com/message/4930032#4930032).